# Subject Identification

Tags: subject-or-object

*Could you please tell me where the bookstore is?*

What is the subject in this sentence? *You* or *bookstore*?

Here we are asking another one by calling *you* and the topic of our question is that *bookstore*. I'm confused which one is really the subject here.

Comment: The subject of *which clause*? Do you see that there are two clauses here, each with a subject and verb? Please note that the place to ask questions like this about basic English is at [ELL.se].

Comment: The subject of the matrix (main) clause is "you". There is also a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question), the subject of which is "the bookstore".

Comment: @ Chappo : Oh! Thank You, Joined just now on ELL :)

Comment: It is possible for a sentence to have more than one subject. In this case, *you* is one subject and *bookstore* is another.

Comment: @NathanM. A prototypical sentence has one subject unless there is a subordinate clause present, which is the case in the OP's example. It's important to bring out that point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a compound sentence and has more than one subject. *You* is the subject of the verb phrase “tell me” and *bookstore* is the subject of “Where is?” *Is* is a state-of-being verb, so the bookstore *is where* it is. The asker is simply trying to find out where *it* is.

Comment: @ Nathan M. Really Appreciating your help for once again! :)

Comment: It is no problem. But please get a second opinion; there may be something I’m missing or misstating.

Comment: @ Nathan M. :O :/ emmm :/ Okay! :)

Comment: There is only one subject of the sentence. There is a subject in the subordinate clause too, but this is not the subject of the sentence.